# Find source code and documentation of Overleaf package

Tags: overleaf, documentation, fontawesome

I am faced with a very specific issue: I wish to know which commands are provided by a package, in this specific case, by fontawesome. For that to happen, I would like to know if there is a standard way for one obtain the full documentation, for each of the imported packages, in Overleaf, as usually packages are shipped with documentation available.

Again, in this specific case, I have found the official website for fontawesome, yet I don't know which version is being imported by Overleaf, which means that I can't narrow down the available icons for that specific version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TeX Live (which is used by Overleaf) can be installed with or without package documentation and sources. Overleaf installs it without documentation.

But you can try to obtain the documentation separately.

Next to Overleaf's "Recompile" button, Overleaf has a button to show the log file. This includes a lot of information, including the versions of all used packages, e.g.

> Package: fontawesome 2016/05/15 v4.6.3.1 font awesome icons

(Of course your project might show something different, especially if you selected another TeX Live version (For the fontawesome package this would require a very old TeX Live version though))

This shows which version you are working with. For some packages you can use this to get the corresponding documentation from the projects repository, but in many cases it's easier to look at up-to-date documentation which often lists changes made in later versions. If you do not have a local TeX Live installation, you can access current documentation through https://texdoc.org. If you e.g. search for `fontawesome` there, you get the documentation for fontawesome v4.6.3.2 which contains a "Change History" showing that the only change between v4.6.3.2 and v4.6.3.1 was the removal of one command.

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for. In my case, after searching for the corresponding entry, just for future reference, it shows `Package: fontawesome 2016/05/15 v4.6.3.1 font awesome icons`. However, the link you have provided me has a certificate error and I can't connect to it using Firefox. After a google search I have found the link for the documentation for version 4.7 - [link](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icons/) - which should probably be good enough, I should probably update anyways!

Comment: @JoséFerreira That's not the documentation of the LaTeX package but the upstream font. The `fontawesome` LaTeX package never got updated beyond v4.6.3.1. (If you want Font Awesome 5, you can use my `fontawesome5` package instead.) Until texdoc.org is fixed, you can find documentation for LaTeX packages also [directly on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fontawesome/doc/fontawesome.pdf).